# Understanding my 96 year old father's US Army discharge papers

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military

[image]I have my father's discharge papers and medals. I am trying to organize and classify his medals properly. 
Line 32 reads - Sicilian, Naples-Foggia, Southern France, Rhineland GO105 WD45

Line 33 reads American defense Service Medal, American Theater Campaign Medal EAME Campaign Medal with 4 Bronze Stars and 1 Bronze Arrowhead, Good Conduct Medal, Victory Ribbon, 1 Service Strip, 5 Overseas Service Bars.

I feel as if I am missing some medals but not sure[![This is the shadow box of his military I made several years ago. Please help. My Dad is 96 Years old and I would like for him to see this before he passes away. All are his original except the Arrowhead patch. The VA visitor recently gave this one to him because he noticed my Dad didn't have one. I do know this Arrowhead is the wrong color. The original should be a blue color with olive green T, if I am correct.

Thank you,
Elizabeth Blair Minor

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Do you know what unit your father served in?

Answer (score 9):

## Sicilian, Naples-Foggia, Southern France, Rhineland GO105 WD45

The first part are combat zones your father served in. They all have specific areas and times defined in GO105 WD45.

"GO105 WD45" is General Order 105 issued by the War Department in 1945. It can be found [on page 293 of this war department document](http://www.benning.army.mil/library/content/Virtual/General%20Orders/GeneralOrders/DAGO1945.pdf). It adds to the "list of battles and campaigns of the United States Army".

This was later [superseded by GO24 WD47](https://history.army.mil/documents/WDGO/WDGO24-1947/WW2campindex.htm) which is much easier to read and has maps.

## [American Defense Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Defense_Service_Medal)

You have two ribbons for that.

## [American Theater Campaign Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Campaign_Medal)

You have a ribbon.

## [EAME Campaign Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European%E2%80%93African%E2%80%93Middle_Eastern_Campaign_Medal)

You have two ribbons for that. The [4 Bronze Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_star#Campaign_stars) indicate he served in four battles. The [Bronze Arrowhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_device) is for participating in an assault landing.

I believe the arrowhead goes on the wearer's right of other devices, so they should be displayed `^ * * * *`.

## [Good Conduct Medal (US Army)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Conduct_Medal_(United_States)#Army_Good_Conduct_Medal)

You have 3 ribbons and 2 medals.

## [Victory Ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_Victory_Medal_(United_States))

I don't see a WWII Victory Ribbon in your display.

## 1 [Service Strip[e]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_stripe)

Each indicates three years of service. I don't see one in your display.

## 5 [Overseas Service Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Service_Bar)

Each indicates six months overseas. You're displaying six.

Answer (score 4):

The bronze stars to the European–African–Middle Eastern Campaign Medal indicates service in four of the designated campaigns. Since one of them is "Southern France", he is a candidate for the Légion d’honneur - to submit an application you can contact your nearest french consulate. More information is found here:

[France Honors American Veterans](https://franceintheus.org/spip.php?article3150)